# App should open links with WebView not with Safari

Tags: objective-c, ios4, safari, uiwebview, uitextview

I've got an UITextView in my app where rss feeds are loaded in. Now I want that when there's a link in the textview and you tab on it, my webview should open that link not safari. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey,
It will be difficult for you to know where you have clicked in your UITextView. 
Honestly the best way for you to do that it to use the [Three20](http://three20.info/) framework.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in a UITextView without significant effort.

Just an idea, but could you not load your RSS feed directly into a UIWebView? - (You can display a HTML formatted string in a UIWebView). Subsequent link presses could then by hijacked using the UIWebView delegate and handled by your application to (for example) open them in another UIWebView. Take a look at the UIWebView interface & delegate to see if it might help.

Hope this helps!

Nick.